# Does Blender game engine support importing models at runtime?

Tags: blender, runtime.exec

I wonder if we can import 3D model such as .fbx at runtime using blender source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have to import a model at runtime. Instead you could add an object through [script](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_release/bge.types.KX_Scene.html?highlight=bge%20add#bge.types.KX_Scene.addObject) or through a [logic brick](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Game_Engine/Logic/Actuators/Edit_Object). If you don't want to store the object that you want to instantiate to be in the playable level, store it in another props scene or layer. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_z01yFl3new&index=35&list=UUY0GR3c0mU2-wg4OGEk84ow) video can demonstrate that (at 5:02).